# Tensorflow on Raspberry:- Restore called with invalid save path './model.ckpt'. file path is: './model.ckpt'

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, computer-vision, ocr

**Update:** [Here the github repository of my project](https://github.com/Marco-DG/Tensorflow-MNIST-digit_recognition)

---

I've trained a digit recognizer model using MNIST on Tensorflow, trained on 64bit windows 10 works very well on Ubuntu 18 too. I've moved the scripts on a Raspberry Pi3 Model B and an error raises:

```
... line 1342, in restore "File path is: %r" % (save_path, file_path))
ValueError: Restore called with invalid save path: './model.ckpt'. File path is: '.model.ckpt'
```

`checkpoint`, `model.ckpt.index`, `model.ckpt.meta` and `model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001` are in the same folder of the scripts.

I've modified a little the code from this [Github repository](https://github.com/niektemme/tensorflow-mnist-predict): restore.py:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(init_op)
saver.restore(sess, "model.ckpt")

prediction=tf.argmax(y_conv,1)

toReturn = []
for value in imvalue:
    toReturn.append(prediction.eval(feed_dict={x: [value],keep_prob: 1.0}, session=sess))

sess.close()
```

> **NOTE: The program works fine on Windows and Ubuntu but not on Raspberry**

It's a week now that I try to make it run, I thought the problem was the path but my attempts are been vain. I've searched a lot on the Internet but what I've found was useless; any help would be appreciated,
many thanks,
Marco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that the problem was the checkpoints files, it seems that a model trained on an x64 architecture whit the x64 **Tensorflow package is incompatible** and cannot be loaded **on an** x64**ARM** whit the Tensorflow package for ARM, or at least whit the versions I have of them, so I've **retrained the model** directly **on the Raspberry** and all works fine now.